# Why do we ignore external pressure on the piston in PV work?

Tags: thermodynamics

For an expanding gas in a container, pushing a piston, the net energy change of the gas should be the work done by the gas on the piston (-ve) plus the work done by the environment on the piston (+ve). But in textbooks, only the work done by the gas on the piston is considered while talking about the gas's change in energy. Why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate, but I'll ask you a question that is related: assuming the piston is vertical, why can we ignore the weight of the piston?

Comment: What? If the process is reversible, the work done by the gas is the _negative_ of the work done on the gas. What's so intricate here?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 The gas is losing energy by doing work on the piston. But is also gaining some due to the work by the environment. So, actually the net work is making the piston move. My question is why do we ignore this positive work on the gas while calculating the gas's change in energy?

Comment: @SeanLake Yeah that's exactly what I'm asking. Maybe we assume the piston to be massless in that case.

Comment: Let me rephrase: when analyzing simple harmonic motion of a vertically hanging spring, what effect does gravity have? Does it alter any conclusions we reach about reversibility of stretching or compressing the string? What net work does gravity do on a full cycle?

Point being: you don't have to ignore it - it's just a waste of time not to.

Comment: I get it for an oscillator, that the effect of gravity is just causing the equilibrium position to change. But how does it apply in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your gas only. Its pression gives work to the piston, yet the gas doesn't interact with the environment. So you don't have to take the work done by the environment on the piston into acount.

Comment: The gas is losing energy by doing work on the piston. But is also gaining some due to the work by the environment. So, actually the net work is making the piston move. My question is why do we ignore this positive work on the gas?

Comment: @BilalKhalid You're only considering the gaz, not the gas and the piston. What is the interaction - *ie.* the force - between the gas and the environment ?

Comment: There isn't a direct interaction. But an indirect one through the piston.

Comment: I didn't understand how you arrived at the conclusion of ignoring the environmental work given there isn't any interaction.

Comment: @BilalKhalid An indirect interaction is not an interaction from a mechanical point of view. For example, consider three masses, and two springs: the first is between masses 1 and 2, and the second between 2 and 3. Now, do mass 1 exchange energy with mass 3?

Comment: The oscillators are coupled so I think a change in energy of mass 1  will have an effect on the energy of mass 3.

Comment: @BilalKhalid You're right, the three systems are linked. However, mass 1 doesn't exchange energy with mass 3. Here, we're talking about mechanical energy, which is *defined* by the work-energy principle. This principle says that a system can give energy to another system only if there is a force between them.

Comment: Yeah you're right. But referring to the case I'm talking about, keeping the work done by the gas aside, the push of the environment will move the piston, pushing against the gas and hence doing work on it. So technically its the piston doing work on the gas, but the energy's coming from the environment. So, for the sake of simplicity we can assume an interaction between the gas and the environment.

Comment: @BilalKhalid "technically it's the piston doing work on the gas": physics is technic, so the environment doesn't do work on the gas. It gives work to the piston, which gives work to the gas. Happily, the piston is supposed to be a rigid body, so every bit of energy given by the environment to the piston is given by the piston to the gas. Here, for the sake of simplicity, you're losing the very accuracy physics needs.

Comment: You're right about the details going on inside. But the point is why do we ignore this work that the piston does on the gas?

Comment: @BilalKhalid No, we are ignoring the work done by the environment on the piston because we are studying the system {gas}, not the system {piston}.